# trying to replace "." with new line (\n) in python, without space after the "."

Tags: python, replace, newline, strip

I'm trying to replace "." with a new line ("\n") in python.

```
input file:
abc. abc
def. def

new input:
Nigel Reuben Rook Williams (15 July 1944 – 21 April 1992) was an English conservator and expert on the restoration of ceramics and glass. From 1961 until his death he worked at the British Museum, where he became the Chief  successful restorations of the Sutton Hoo helmet and the Portland Vase.

Joining
```

code:

```
test_file=open(path,'r')
test_file_1=open(new_path,'w')

for line in test_file:
    test_file_1.write(line.replace('.','\n'))

test_file.close()
test_file_1.close()
```

i want to delete the space before the new line.

```
expected new output:
nigel reuben rook williams july april was an english  restoration of ceramics and glass
from until his death he worked at the british museum where he became the 
chief conservator of ceramics and glass in
there his work included the successful restorations of the sutton hoo helmet 
and the portland vase
joining
```

Comment: `line.replace('. ','\n')` - _

Comment: @OlvinRoght  2 more issues: 1- i have line in text file for example: "hello. world lala." for the first "." the replace work, for the second "." in the end of the line it doesn't work. 2- also i would like to delete the gap between two lines. for example "abc" and then new line and gap for 1 more line (that i want to delete)

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide real input/output in your question?

Comment: sure, look at the new_input.

Comment: @OlvinRoght sure, look at the new_input.

Answer (score 1):

after dot, there are white spaces. you can use `line.replace('. ','\n')`.

or you can use:

```
for line in test_file:
    words = line.split('.')
    for word in words:
        test_file_1.write(word.strip()+'\n')
```

Comment: but .. `line.split('. ')`